# How do I input password by clicking image with onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to enter-in a password (without typing on keyboard) by clicking on image(s) on my html page with onclick function or any other action. How can I do this? I tried the code below, which worked for plain text by didn't work for my password-type entry (as seen below). Can someone pls help me?

Here are my codes:

```
<form style=" margin-left:200px; font-weight:600">
     <fieldset>
     <legend>STEP II:</legend>
     <input id="psx2" type="password"> 
     <p id="psx3">all the way</p> 
     <p id="psx4">the ramp flies</p> 

     <script>
     function myFunction()
     {
 x=document.getElementById("psx2");  // Find the element
     x.innerHTML="12345";    // Change the content

     x=document.getElementById("psx3");  // Find the element
     x.innerHTML="Hello!";    // Change the content

     x=document.getElementById("psx4");  // Find the element
     x.innerHTML="Hey!";     // Change the content
     }
     </script>

     <a href="#"> 
     <img src="images/colourimages/red.jpg" 
     alt="red not"
     onclick="myFunction()" 
     width="50" 
     height="50" 
     id="red" />
     </a>

     </fieldset>
     </form>
```

This is the result:

you will notice that nothing showed on the password field. Please can someone help? I will appreciate it..

Comment: You have to use `value` instead of `innerHtml`.

Comment: So if i viewed your HTML source, i could sniff out the passwords right ?

Comment: Why is this even a password field?  You're not having the user enter a password.  It might as well be a text or hidden field.  (It's not really a "password" if you tell the user what it is, which you're doing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form elements do not use `.innerHTML` to change the content you need to use `.value`

Comment: @Ifeanyi Omeata, change x.innerHTML="12345"; to x.value="12345";

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` for `input elements` like,

```
function myFunction()
{
   x=document.getElementById("psx2");  //  Input element
   x.value="12345";    // Change the content

   // innerHTMl is fine for p or div tags
   .......
```